# RxSwift iOS Observable FIFO Queue Implementation in Swift 2

Tags: swift, ios, rx-swift

I am trying to develop an Observable queue that executes given Observable chains one at a time. The code will be used to encode videos on an iPhone and only one queue will be needed per launch, therefore it is declared as `static`. It seems to work but I am not sure I covered all the edge cases.

Below is the implementation as well as the test. I use Swift 2 with the latest supported RxSwift pod.

```
class SomeObject {}

// Implementation
extension SomeObject {
    // Will be created once per runtime
    static let queueSubject: PublishSubject<Observable<Int>> = PublishSubject()

    // Will be called once per runtime
    static func consumeQueue() {

        let queueName = "someQueue"
        let queue = dispatch_queue_create(queueName, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
        let scheduler = SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(queue: queue, internalSerialQueueName: queueName)
        let lock = NSLock()

        lock.unlock()

        _ = queueSubject
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .doOnNext({ _ in
                print("queue locking")
                lock.lock()
                print("queue locked")
            })
            .flatMap({
                return $0.observeOn(scheduler).subscribeOn(scheduler)
            })
            .doOnNext({
                print("queue unlocking")
                lock.unlock()
                print("queue unlocked")
            })
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(
                onNext: { _ in
                    print("queue onNext")
                },
                onError: { _ in
                    print("queue error")
                },
                onCompleted: {
                    print("queue completed")
                },
                onDisposed: {}
        )
    }
}

// Test
extension SomeObject {
    static func testQueue() {
        SomeObject.consumeQueue()

        let test1 = Observable<Int>.timer(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                .doOnCompleted({
                    print("test 1")
                })

        let test2 = Observable<Int>.timer(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                .doOnCompleted({
                    print("test 2")
                })

        SomeObject.queueSubject.onNext(test1)
        SomeObject.queueSubject.onNext(test2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to Swift 3, do it before it's too late!

Comment: Eventually it will happen but current code base is quite large and have some heavy dependencies written in Swift 2. It is impossible to migrate to Swift 3 in a week. A month long migration is scheduled to next autumn.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, even in Swift 2. Where is the definition of `SomeObject`? (Only two extensions are here.) Where is the definition of `encodeLock`? What is `lock` supposed to be for? (It isn't being used.)

Comment: @DanielT. I fixed the typos occurred during reducing the irrelevant code. It should compile now.

Comment: What is the expected output? I'm getting `queue locking\nqueue locked\nqueue locking` then a crash due to a deadlock.

Comment: Expected output is "queue locking\nqueue locked\nqueue unlocking\nqueue unlocked\nqueue onNext" repeated for each test, in this case 2 times.  It should adapt to any number of test attempts.